# condition not working when subtracting 2 dates and the difference is greater than some number

Tags: oracle12c

I have given the below where clause but the query gives an output irrespective of whether it is greater than 4 or not. Could you please let me know what is wrong

```
where to_number(
    end_date - (case when start_date > to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') 
    then start_date 
    else to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') end)
) > 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query works for me in both Oracle 11 and Oracle 12:

```
with data (start_date, end_date)
  as (
    select  to_date('31-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('05-02-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('31-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('31-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('01-05-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('31-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('15-11-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('01-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('06-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('01-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('05-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('01-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('04-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('01-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('03-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    )
select start_date, end_date from data
where to_number(
    end_date - (case when start_date > to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') 
    then start_date 
    else to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') end)
) > 4


"START_DATE"    "END_DATE"
31-JAN-14   05-FEB-14
31-DEC-13   01-MAY-14
31-OCT-14   15-NOV-14
01-OCT-14   06-OCT-14
```

Note that 4 rows of the data were selected.
I would suggest adding a column to your query that matches your criteria to see what is going on; following is a query that displays the criteria value:

```
with data (start_date, end_date)
  as (
    select  to_date('31-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('05-02-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('31-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('31-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('01-05-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('31-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('15-11-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('01-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('06-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('01-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('05-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('01-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('04-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    union all 
    select  to_date('01-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as start_date,  to_date('03-10-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') as end_date from dual
    )
select start_date, end_date,
 to_number(
    end_date - (case when start_date > to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') 
    then start_date 
    else to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') end)) as elapsed
from data
where to_number(
    end_date - (case when start_date > to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') 
    then start_date 
    else to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') end)
) > 4


"START_DATE"  "END_DATE"  "ELAPSED"
31-JAN-14     05-FEB-14          5
31-DEC-13     01-MAY-14        120
31-OCT-14     15-NOV-14         15
01-OCT-14     06-OCT-14          5
```

To ensure the opposite criteria worked, I changed the criteria to

```
where to_number(
    end_date - (case when start_date > to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') 
    then start_date 
    else to_date('01-01-2014','dd-mm-yyyy') end)
) <= 4
```

and got back this:

```
"START_DATE"    "END_DATE"  "ELAPSED"
31-DEC-13       01-JAN-14          0
01-OCT-14       05-OCT-14          4
01-OCT-14       04-OCT-14          3
01-OCT-14       03-OCT-14          2
```